# R loop running slower as time goes on

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp, network-analysis

I am using a function provided by someone else. The code does the basic function of creating networks between places. But it runs slower and slower as time goes on. I meant to simplify the function so as to publish it more clearly but then I think it is rather better to publish the full code... I think something can be improved within the for loop. Can anyone help me out?

Best wishes,

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(igraph)

spnetBuild <- function(sites, siteid, edges, edgew, cutoff=0, verbose=TRUE){  
if (verbose){
    print("Creating spatial lines...")
    flush.console()
    pb <- txtProgressBar(min=1, max=nrow(sites), style=3)
}
edges$Path <- paste("from_",as.character(edges$From),"_to_",as.character(edges$To),sep="")
check <- TRUE
for (i in 1:nrow(sites)){
    if (verbose){ setTxtProgressBar(pb,i) }
    xyi <- coordinates(sites[i,])
    tos <- sites[-i,]
  
    for (j in 1:nrow(tos)){
        lid <- paste("from_",as.character(sites@data[i,siteid]),"_to_",as.character(tos@data[j,siteid]),sep="")
        wt <- edges[edges$Path == lid,edgew]

        if (wt >= cutoff){
            xyj <- coordinates(tos[j,])
            L <- Line(rbind(t(matrix(xyi)),t(matrix(xyj))))
            Ls <- Lines(list(L),j)
            newSL0 <- SpatialLines(list(Ls))
            newSL <- spChFIDs(newSL0, lid)
            df <- data.frame(Weight=wt, row.names=lid)
            newSL <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(newSL,df)
        plot(newSL)
        print(newSL)
            if (check){
                sitenet <- newSL
                check <- FALSE
            } else {
                sitenet <- spRbind(sitenet,newSL)
            }
        }
    }
}
if (verbose){ close(pb) }
return(sitenet)
```

}

Comment: Yes, you a bind (spbind in this case) function inside the loop.  This involves copying and deleting objects in memory over and over again and can be quite slow as the object grows in size.

Comment: I see. Thanks, @Dave2e ! Could you please provide any suggestions on this?

Comment: Generally it is best to pre allocate the space up front before the loop or store the information in a list and then bind after the loop.  I don’t know if that would work for your sitenet variable.

Comment: I kinda understand what you mean. I will try that. Thanks!@Dave2e